# How pass cookie throw node server to REST API in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, cookies, server-side-rendering

I have an Angular app with server side rendering. I wont to execute one rest request only on server side, so I place such code in if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) block.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer} from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object){ }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      /* Client only code. */
    }

    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      /* Server only code. */
      this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/tracking', { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Init tracking")
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Everyting ok, this http.get called only in server side, but httprequest on my API comes without cookies. So, in my node server I add cookie throw cookie-parser:

```
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

And I saw them in console.log(req.cookies), but they still don't come to the API.

**server.ts**

```
import "zone.js/dist/zone-node";
import "reflect-metadata";
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
import * as express from "express";
import {join} from "path";
import {readFileSync} from "fs";
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from "@nguniversal/express-engine";
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader";
import {CookieService} from "ngx-cookie-service";

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    CookieService,
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

/* - Example Express Rest API endpoints -
  app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
*/

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// ALl regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Cookies req: ', req.cookies);
  res.render('index', { req });

});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

How can I pass cookie throw node & get them on my rest end point in API?

Answer (score 0):

Angular universal doesn't automatically set the cookies it received from the Client request to all its HTTP request while doing SSR, as it cannot verify if the cookie should be attached to a particular HTTP request made to a domain or not.

Though you can set it through for `http.get(url, options)` request, by setting the cookie header like below

```
// DO THIS only on server
if(isPlatformServer){
    // options: RequestOptionsArgs
     let options = {};
     options.headers = new Headers();
     options.headers.set('cookie', 'cookies that you need to attach');
}
http.get(url, options)
```

Check out the following article for detailed information.
https://davidsekar.com/angular/set-cookie-in-angular-universal-during-ssr

Comment: I solved this problem. Now, the problem is that cookies do not come from rest api (Spring) to node (http interceptor). 
Please, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248072/how-to-alllow-node-express-server-to-accept-cookie-from-spring-angular-4